# How to write events for a custom component in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, events, custom-component

I have written a custom component for drawing a circle in Flex. But When I try to write a click event or mouseDown event for that component, it doesn't work.

I have the circle component inside a VBox.

```
 <mx:VBox label="Currents Quote" width="100%" backgroundColor="#DDDDDD">

<comp:MyCircle id="circlle" x1="175" y1="150" 
                    radius="140" click='{Alert.show("Hello");}'
                    mouseDown="handleMouseDown(event);"/>
<comp:MyLine x1="175" y1="104"/> 
 </mx:VBox>

  private function handleMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {

        var pt:Point = new Point(event.localX, event.localY);
        pt = event.target.localToGlobal(pt);   
        pt = circlle.globalToContent(pt);   
        var whichColor:String = "border area";

        if (pt.x < 150) {
            if (pt.y < 150)
                whichColor = "red";
            else
                whichColor = "blue";
        }
        else {
            if (pt.y < 150)
                whichColor = "green";
            else
                whichColor = "magenta";
        }

        Alert.show("You clicked on the " + whichColor);
      }
```

Circle component:

```
  package components
  {
 import mx.core.UIComponent;

 public class MyCircle extends UIComponent
 {
       public var x1:int; 
          public var y1:int; 
          public var radius:int; 

          override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void 
         { 
        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        graphics.drawCircle(x1, y1, radius); 

        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        graphics.drawCircle(x1, y1, radius-40); 

        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        graphics.drawCircle(x1, y1, radius-100);
         }
     }
 }
```

The "Hello" Alert is displayed only at a particular point and guess is, at the point, (175,150) the x, y co-ordinates of the circle. But shouldn't it be displayed wherever I click on the MyCircle component?? how to enable it in that way?

Also the mouseDown function doesn't work for MyCircle,but if have the event for the VBox, the Alerts are displayed. Why so? Can someone guide me?

Should I write events for custom components in a different manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is applicable or not, but there is a bug where some UIComponents don't recognized click/mouseDown events correctly unless they have a background color. See if adding a background color to your circle helps.

Comment: yes,it Sure did.. I changed the background color, and now the event is triggered. THanks a lot :-)

Comment: Some background I've found on this, it seems that clicking on the border of backgroundless items will produce a click event, or even the text inside it. The same works for drag acceptance in drag & drop events. It may be the original designers intent that the lack of visual representation makes the control transparent, even to events. This may not even really be a bug, I could come up with a few ways to use such control positively, but when we don't know about it, it can frustrate us to no end.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a few errors in your code, for example, you're missing script tags around your actionscript, and you might need to import Alert.

```
 <mx:VBox label="Currents Quote" width="100%" backgroundColor="#DDDDDD">

<comp:MyCircle id="circlle" x1="175" y1="150" 
                    radius="140" click='{Alert.show("Hello");}'
                    mouseDown="handleMouseDown(event);"/>
<comp:MyLine x1="175" y1="104"/> 
 </mx:VBox>

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  private function handleMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {

        var pt:Point = new Point(event.localX, event.localY);
        pt = event.target.localToGlobal(pt);   
        pt = circlle.globalToContent(pt);   
        var whichColor:String = "border area";

        if (pt.x < 150) {
            if (pt.y < 150)
                whichColor = "red";
            else
                whichColor = "blue";
        }
        else {
            if (pt.y < 150)
                whichColor = "green";
            else
                whichColor = "magenta";
        }

        Alert.show("You clicked on the " + whichColor);
      }
]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: I had those tags.. I just didn't write the entire code here.. Thought only the function is important and left out those parts.. :-)

Comment: oh haha... make sure you note if you do that, some of us are easily confused;)